# Android phone causing wifi degradation

Tags: wireless-networking, routing, wireless-router, android

Earlier today, while working on a laptop which is connected to the internet via WiFi, my internet connection dropped.  After restarting the router, the internet worked again for a few minutes before dropping again.  I confirmed that this was the case for all my electronics.

I confirmed that the internet coming into my residence is working and that the problem is related to the WiFi.  I tried to isolate the issue by resetting the router and connecting devices to the WiFi (5G network) one at a time.  While debugging, I found that the WiFi works fine until I connect to it with my Android Phone (Moto X4 - Android 9).  Upon connecting the phone to the network, I'm finding pings increase from 1-50ms ping and ~1% drop rate to the router to pings of 150-1000ms+ occurring every few seconds and a 30-50% drop rate.  I tried connecting with my wife's phone (same model) as well, separately, and experience the same result.

Last note, is I find if I connect the phone to the 2.4GHz network, it doesn't interfere with devices on the 5GHz network so it seems that this is a wireless issue and not the router.

I would appreciate any advice, solutions or possible debug steps.

- **Phone**: Moto X4 - Android 9, Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
- **Router**: TL-Link Archer AX3000 (1 month old), 5GHz: 802.11a/n/ac/ax mixed, 2.4GHz: 802.11b/g/n/ax mixed

Comment: What version of WiFi does the phone support? What version of WiFi is the access point?

Comment: I've updated the access point and phone info with the supported WiFi versions.  Access point has OFDMA enabled.

Comment: I've also discovered that with both my wife's and my phone both connected to the access point on the 2.4GHz spectrum, our phones seem to conflict blocking each other.

Comment: So your phone is WiFi 5 while your router is WiFi 6. Adjustment of the channel on the 2.4 GHz should resolve the conflict with your phones. These other devices are WiFi 6 devices?

Comment: I appreciate the help.

As I understand, WiFi 6 should be backward compatible with WiFi 5 devices.  Nevertheless, I tried configuring the router to use WiFi 5 but the change did not seem to affect anything.  Also, the devices have been working fine for about a month with the router.  This issue came up suddenly without me knowingly making any modifications to the phones or the access point which is what leaves me most confused.

Comment: Your question contains two model names: "Moto E4" and "Moto X4"  Is the first or the second a typo?

Comment: Sorry, correct model is Moto X4.

Comment: so, there is/was an issue with chromecast-supporting devices absolutely flooding the LAN with mDNS requests eventually having the router close down traffic. Not sure the specific fix, but see, for example, ( https://www.myce.com/news/confirmed-issue-google-cast-causes-temporarily-wifi-drops-around-world-83428/ ) and ( https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/2050/ )

Comment: Thanks for the info Yorik.  I figure it's either my something on my access point broke or something on my Android devices changed.  I checked if any apps had updated on the phones that might be causing them to flood the network but nothing on my wife's phone updated yesterday so a broken update wouldn't explain things.